# arrow keys for line editing during zsh read builtin

Tags: zsh

I have a little zsh script for prompting the user for some input:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
IFS="$(printf "\n\t")"
printf "${1-query}: " 1>&2
read -r query
echo "${query}"
```

If I type something at the prompt then try to use the arrow keys to go back and edit, I get `^[[D` instead. My `TERM` env is `xterm`. How can I get the arrow keys working properly for line editing as if this was a regular zsh command line?

Here's the output of `setopt` in case any of these are relevant:

```
emacs
noflowcontrol
histexpiredupsfirst
histfindnodups
histignorealldups
histignoredups
histsavenodups
histverify
incappendhistory
interactive
interactivecomments
monitor
nonomatch
promptsubst
shinstdin
zle
```

Comment: Possibly related: [Using shell's read command with live editing functionality (readline like)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112109/using-shells-read-command-with-live-editing-functionality-readline-like)

Comment: Ah, from that I learned about `vared` which seems to do the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on a comment linking to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112109/using-shells-read-command-with-live-editing-functionality-readline-like), I learned about `vared`. Here's what I used which works great:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
IFS="$(printf "\n\t")"
query=
vared -p "${1-query}: " query 
echo "${query}"
```

Comment: You'd use `IFS=$'\n\t'` to set IFS to newline and tab. However here your code doesn't use `$IFS`.

Comment: You'd also need `echo -E - "$query"` for `echo` to output the content of `$query` verbatim. Or the more portable: `print -r -- "$query"` like in `ksh` or even better `printf '%s\n' "$query"` (POSIX)

Comment: vared wont work inside subshells, try `vared -c variable` vs `( vared -c variable )`. To solve spawn a new zsh process like this: `variable=$(declare read_return_status; vared -c input; read_return_status="$?"; printf "%s" "$input"; exit "$read_return_status" )"` that way you also keep the read return status to detect read failures.